# Error when using os.system to call PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, powershell-5.0

I receive the following error when I attempt to call `powershell` from a Python function:

> Cannot load PSReadline module. Console is running without PSReadline.

I have a function called `ps_cli()` which is: `os.system("powershell -NoProfile")`

When I call it I get the following behavior/error:
[image]

This previously worked on Windows 7 and 8 machines (which I don't have access to currently) and from some of the things I read might be something to do with PowerShell 5 which is on Windows 10 machines. The idea behind the tool I'm writing is that it would work with any modern version of Windows on an account with appropriate privileges. As there are more advanced scripts I am writing and this seems to cause a few second delay I would like to find out how to get rid of this without doing:

> Open Powershell using the parameter `-PSConsoleFile` and a PSConsoleFile that you previously exported with `Export-Console`.

Which was suggested in a forum post I saw. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could this be because of the policy in Powershell not to run untrusted scripts?

Comment: @GLaDOS No, I don't believe so as it does end up launching the console. Additionally, there is no 'script' it is trying to execute so I doubt the ExecutionPolicy would come in to play. Definitely worth checking though.

Comment: You nailed it @GLaDOS

Comment: we do what we must, because we can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PSReadline`-module is a new built-in module in Powershell 5.0 (on Win10) that provides enhanced console experience. Since it's built-in there shouldn't be a problem with executionpolicy (even though it isn't signed for some reason), but it never hurts to check. Does this work?

```
os.system("powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass")
```

Are you using a third-party console? The module may not be compatible with consoles other than `conhost.exe` (default in windows used by cmd and powershell).

A dirty workaround is to simply clear the screen:

```
os.system("powershell -NoProfile -NoExit -Command cls")
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried the execution policy and that surprisingly fixed it, so that's cool. I am using a 3rd party console - Cmder (Conemu based console) - but it looks like it's good to go! :)